# Matplotlib in pyqt5 plot when ı convert .exe return IndexError: tuple index out of range

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5, pyinstaller, exe

I add matplotlib pyplot to my Project When i run it work seamless but when ı convert my code to exe Thats give me
 `tuple index out of range`

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout,QPushButton,QWidget,QApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
import sys
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


class MplCanvas(FigureCanvas):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=50, height=40, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
        super(MplCanvas, self).__init__(fig)

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self): # Constructor Method
        super().__init__() 
        self.initUI() 
    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("MatPlotLib Live Graph Example")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("/images/pp.jpg"))
        self.setGeometry(300,300,500,500)
        self.mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)
        self.x = [0 , 1 , 2 , 3]
        self.y = [0 , 1 , 2 , 3]
        # ----------------------------------------------------------------
        self.exampleCanvas = MplCanvas(self, width=5, height=4, dpi=100)
        self.exampleCanvas.axes.plot(self.x, self.y , label="Legend")
        # ----------------------------------------------------------------
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.exampleCanvas)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I am writing code bellow for convert my code to exe:

`pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole --icon=roboticon.ico --clean .\canvasmatplot.py`

but ı take this return.
`tuple index out of range`

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Python --version 3.10 when ı updated my Pytyhon --version at 3.10.4 my problem was solved .